# Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "..."

Tags: php, forms, symfony, testing, phpunit

this is my form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class JoseType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre')
            ->add('apellido')
            ->add('edad')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Jose'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_jose';
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
use AppBundle\Form\JoseType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class ProjectTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testForm()
    {
         $form = $this->factory->create(JoseType::class);

    }
}
```

To running test receive this:

> Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "AppBundle\Form\JoseType"

I have symfony **2.6.13**.

In symfony 3.2 works, but 2.6 doesn't work, Why? ... any idea?

Comment: Clear the cache (`php app/console cache:clear [--env=prod --no-debug]`), are you using composers autoload map? If so, try dumping it again (`composer dump-autoload -a`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that in symfony 2.6 you should make instance of your type and pass it to create function.

```
$type = new JoseType();  $form = this->factory->create($type);
```

Code you wrote is valid since version 2.8.

The second problem is in

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
```

since symfony 2.7 you should use

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
```

instead setDefaultOptions function. So your code will work in symfony 2.6 and will not in symfony 3.2